# python system tray error not working with schedule

Tags: python, windows, pysimplegui

when i run this code and do login after. i am doing start system schedule in python when i start schedule so s system tray icon will be created on system tray and system tray i have given event for system exit form this code but problem is i can't exit after click on this when i start the schedule

please someone help me solve this problem[image]
username: emp
password: emp

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import requests
from psgtray import SystemTray
import json
import schedule
from schedule import *
import gtts
import threading
import time


def make_sch(user_id: object, emp_name: object):
    schedule.every(4).seconds.do(func_msg, user_id, emp_name)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(4)


def func_msg(user_id: object, emp_name: object):
    response_msg = '{ "msg": "Data Found","status": 1,"Data": "hello team","id": 2}'
    response_msg_json: object = json.loads(response_msg)
    print(response_msg_json)
    if str(response_msg_json['status']) == '1' and str(response_msg_json['id']) != '':
        sg.theme('DarkTeal9')  # Add a touch of color
        layout = [[sg.Text(response_msg_json['Data'])],
                  [sg.Text('Enter your Acknowledge'), sg.Multiline(size=(50, 5), key='textbox')],
                  [sg.Button('Enter'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
                  [sg.Text(size=(40, 1), key='ACK_OUTPUT')]]

        # Create the Window
        window = sg.Window('Team Alert', layout)
        # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
        while True:
            event, values = window.read()
            if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
                break
            elif event == 'Enter' and values['textbox'] == '':
                window['ACK_OUTPUT'].update('Please enter your Acknowledgement', text_color='red')
            else:
                window['ACK_OUTPUT'].update('', text_color='red')
                response_update = '{"msg": "Data Found","status": 1}'
                response_update_json: object = json.loads(response_update)
                sg.Popup('Thanks For Your Acknowledgement!!')
                window.close()

        window.close()


def main():
    menu = ['',
            ['Show Window', 'Hide Window', '---', '!Disabled Item', 'Exit']]
    tooltip = 'Team Alert'
    sg.theme('DarkTeal9')
    layout = [[sg.Text("* Enter Your Id")],
              [sg.Input(key='emp_id')],
              [sg.Text(size=(40, 1))],
              [sg.Text("* Enter Your Password")],
              [sg.Input(key='emp_pass')],
              [sg.Text(size=(40, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Button('Login')]]

    window = sg.Window('Team Alert', layout, finalize=True, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
    tray = SystemTray(menu, single_click_events=True, window=window, tooltip=tooltip)
    tray.show_message('Team Alert', 'Team Alert Started!')
    sg.cprint(sg.get_versions())
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if values['emp_id'] and values['emp_pass']:
            response = '{ "msg": "Sucessfully login", "status": 1}'
            login_data_json: object = json.loads(response)
            if str(login_data_json['status']) == '1':
                window.hide()
                tray.show_icon()
                window['-OUTPUT-'].update(login_data_json['msg'], text_color='yellow')
                emp_id = values['emp_id']
                emp_name = 'emp'
                make_sch(emp_id, emp_name)
            else:
                window['-OUTPUT-'].update(login_data_json['msg'], text_color='red')
            if event == 'Login':
                sg.Popup(login_data_json['msg'])
        else:
            window['-OUTPUT-'].update('** Username and Password is required', text_color='red')
        if event == tray.key:
            sg.cprint(f'Team Alert Event = ', values[event], c='white on red')
            event = values[event]
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            sg.Popup("You are Logout!!")
            break

        sg.cprint(event, values)
        tray.show_message(title=event, message=values)

        if event in ('Show Window', sg.EVENT_SYSTEM_TRAY_ICON_DOUBLE_CLICKED):
            window.un_hide()
            window.bring_to_front()
        elif event in ('Hide Window', sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT):
            window.hide()
            tray.show_icon()
        elif event == 'Hide Icon':
            tray.hide_icon()
        elif event == 'Show Icon':
            tray.show_icon()
        elif event == 'Change Tooltip':
            tray.set_tooltip(values['-IN-'])

    tray.close()
    window.close()

    print('this is event', event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well yes, your code remains in an infinite loop in `make_sch()`. You'll probably want to rework your program logic so you don't have a (sub)function with an infinite loop.

Comment: but what is the solution sir ?

Comment: I just told you: rework your program logic so you don't end up in a subfunction with an infinite loop (in the main thread anyway). You already have one `while True:` loop in your `main()`; that should be your only main loop.

Comment: sir, i have removed loop in sub function after this same problem i am facing

Comment: sorry sir, i am working on this first time

Answer (score 0):

Your code have lot of problems, like

- Execution blocked when call `schedule`
- Update GUI in `schedule`
- Wrong event for `SystemTray`
- something else.

Different code by using multithread to call `schedule`, update GUI in main loop and event generated in multithread by call `window.write_event_value`.

```py
import time
import threading

import schedule
from psgtray import SystemTray
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def loop(window):
    schedule.every(4).seconds.do(update_gui, window)
    while running:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

def update_gui(window):
    global user
    window.write_event_value("Func_MSG", user)
    time.sleep(1)
    window.write_event_value("Func_MSG_Close", None)

def popup_win(username):
    sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
    return sg.Window('Team Alert', [[sg.Text(f'Hello, {username.title()}')]], finalize=True)

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

users = {'James':'1234', 'Mary':'5678'}

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Username'), sg.Input(key='Username')],
    [sg.Text('Password'), sg.Input(key='Password')],
    [sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='Message')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Login"), sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window("test", layout, finalize=True)

tooltip = 'Team Alert'
menu = ['', ['Show Window', 'Hide Window', 'Exit']]
tray = SystemTray(menu, single_click_events=True, window=window, tooltip=tooltip)
running, user = False, None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == '-TRAY-':
        case = values[event]
        if case == 'Exit':
            break
        elif case in ('Show Window', sg.EVENT_SYSTEM_TRAY_ICON_DOUBLE_CLICKED):
            window.un_hide()
            window.bring_to_front()
        elif case in ('Hide Window', sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT):
            window.hide()
            tray.show_icon()

    if event == 'Login':
        username, password = values['Username'], values['Password']
        if username in users and users[username]==password:
            window.hide()
            window['Message'].update('Login successful !')
            user = username
            if not running:
                running = True
                threading.Thread(target=loop, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()
        else:
            window['Message'].update("Wrong username and/or password !")

    elif event == "Func_MSG":
        username = values[event]
        win = popup_win(username)

    elif event == "Func_MSG_Close":
        if win:
            win.close()

running = False
tray.close()
window.close()
```

Following code show how to use option `timeout` to call function periodically without using `schedule`.

```py
from psgtray import SystemTray
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup_win(username):
    sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text(f'Hello, {username.title()}')],
        [sg.Button('OK')],
    ]
    sg.Window('Team Alert', layout).read(close=True)

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

users = {'James':'1234', 'Mary':'5678'}

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Username'), sg.Input(key='Username')],
    [sg.Text('Password'), sg.Input(key='Password')],
    [sg.Text('', expand_x=True, key='Message')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Login"), sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window("test", layout, finalize=True)

tooltip = 'Team Alert'
menu = ['', ['Show Window', 'Hide Window', 'Exit']]
tray = SystemTray(menu, single_click_events=True, window=window, tooltip=tooltip)
running, user = False, None

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=4000)

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == '-TRAY-':
        case = values[event]
        if case == 'Exit':
            break
        elif case in ('Show Window', sg.EVENT_SYSTEM_TRAY_ICON_DOUBLE_CLICKED):
            window.un_hide()
            window.bring_to_front()
        elif case in ('Hide Window', sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT):
            window.hide()
            tray.show_icon()

    if event == 'Login':
        username, password = values['Username'], values['Password']
        if username in users and users[username]==password:
            window['Message'].update('Login successful !')
            user = username
            running = True
        else:
            window['Message'].update("Wrong username and/or password !")

    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT and running and user:
        popup_win(user)

tray.close()
window.close()
```

Comment: it is working good but always open new window and close old window . it is possible we can hold the window when user submit the acknowledgment? thanks!!!

Comment: Login window not closed, just hide, you can remove statement `window.hide()` under `if username in users and users[username]==password:`

Comment: thanks!!! json yang it is working fine